# Datepicker works in IE error in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: php, javascript

Web form with date picker, one of the fields is cdate , I use jsdatepick for this field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"cdate",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

    };
</script>



<form method="POST" action="insert_record.php">

<tr>
 <td style="width: 143px">Call Date:
 </td>
<td style="width: 472px">
<input type=text id="cdate" name="cdate"  size=40 style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;">
</td>
```

and the form submit php is

```
<?
$cdate=$_POST['cdate'];
$db="call";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "sql", "sql");
//$link = mysql_connect("localhost",$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die("Select Error: ".mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (cdate) VALUES ('$cdate')")or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
print "Record added\n";
?>
```

however once submitted I get message saying ::

> Notice: Undefined index: cdate in d:\web\apache\htdocs\callz\submit_record.php on line 4

this message only occurs in Firefox or Chrome, works fine in any version of IE
any ideas? Note there are other variables besides cdate, all of those variables enter into the table without issue, just seems to be the datepick one.  I have tried another datepick and this doesn't happen, only with the jsdatepick, but jsdatepick is so much more suitable. Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You **never** closed your form tag.

So essentially Chrome and FF close the form tag for you and you get this:

```
<form method="POST" action="insert_record.php"> </form> << NOTHING HERE!

<tr>
 <td style="width: 143px">Call Date:
 </td>
<td style="width: 472px">
<input type=text id="cdate" name="cdate"  size=40 style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;">
</td>
```

Also **PLEASE DO NOT USE `mysql_*` FUNCTIONS**

Try using prepared functions with PDO or mysqli instead ([see this **big red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#function.mysql-connect-soft-deprecation-notice)).

What you have is prone to a **HUGE** [bobby table](http://bobby-tables.com/) issue...

Comment: My guess is this is simply a small set of the actual markup. OP hasn't posted everything.